# Weird behaviour while resolving a deadlock

Tags: c, pthreads, deadlock, semaphore

I had an exercise for class a few weeks ago, my solution was good, but I noticed some weird behaviour when observing it for a longer time.
The exercise was generating a deadlock with two posix threads and then to resolve it. (I abstracted the solution so it has no unnecessary code.

The scenario is the following:

- I have two threads who share two fictional resources
- both threads start in sequence and then try to occupy both resources (in sequence too)
- both threads have different time spans for occupying
- when a thread has both resources he works for 5 seconds and then frees the resources and takes a break, when the break is over he begins again with trying to occupy both resources
- every 8 seconds a function checkes if both threads have the state waiting (both threads have ONE resource and are waiting for the second)
- when a deadlock occures, the thread who worked more is getting canceled and then restarted

Here comes the problem, depending on the machine and the compilerflags the output says that e.g. thread A is cancelled but then thread B started. I tried it on different computers with different compilers, with different istallations. 
Weird is that I compile with `gcc -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -pthread -lrt` and the problem occures with the second deadlock, but when I remove -Wall and -Werror the problems comes with the 3. deadlock 0o

I uploaded the source [here](http://pastebin.com/cUxStRHR). Compile flags are in the source, I tried gcc and clang.
And I also tried Ubuntu 13.04 and Arch. 
[Here](http://pastebin.com/1KAbpcEj) is the output, I marked the lines with "-->"

Did I forget something so this effect appears? I don't think that there are bugs in some libs.

Comment: I am not getting the same effect you are. Can you please post the output you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the address of a local variable to the thread. And that this local variable may no longer exist when the thread starts and you are dereferencing the address location that *used* to hold the local variable but which now holds something else.

Since it is in the stack space of the program you aren't getting a segfault.

Here's a highlight of the problem areas of code and how it can be caused:

```
void resolve_deadlock()
{
    void *pthread_exit_state;
    int id_a = THREAD_A;
    int id_b = THREAD_B;

   <some code to detect deadlocks and kill a thread>

 /* restart the killed thread */
 if (pthread_create(&threads[THREAD_B], NULL, &thread_function, (void *) &id_b) != 0) {
                    perror("Create THREAD_B\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
}
```

So the program runs and:

1. resolve_deadlock is called
2. thread X is killed
3. pthread_create is called to create a thread
4. resolve_deadlock function ends
5. stack is over written on next function call
6. The OS swaps us out and runs another thread
7. thread X runs and dereferences our local var which no longer exists -> undefined behaviour.

Comment: So I assume making id_a and id_b global would solve the mistake? I could swear I tried that yesterday evening and it still was present, but I tried it again now and it seems to work 0o (maybe I forgot something yesterday)
But do you have an idea why I get different behaviour when I remove the -Wall and -Werror flags? They just seem to set compiler output and not change the compilation.

Comment: And is there an other way of solving this without making the vars global?

Comment: The different behaviour you are seeing is due to when the threads get scheduled. If you run the same compiled program multiple times then you'll see the error on different runs (sometimes the local var will exist sometimes it won't).

Comment: The id var needs to be global or at least available to the function which is using it. Thus it could be local to the main function and passed (by reference) to the function which needs it.